# Using React Hooks How Can I Have two search inputs that work together to filter results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, components, react-hooks

I apologize if this is unclear. Let me know if any of this need clarification.

I have two search input. One that sorts by name and another that sorts by tags. Filtering the names was easy enough since I was grabbing that data from an API. However, filtering the data by tags is proving difficult. What would be the best way to set this up?

I have three main components: Search.js Profile.js and Tags.js. Search just passes the user input down. Profile loops over the APi data and filters by name. The Tags component allows the user to add and remove tags. This is placed inside the .map in profile. Since the tags component is inserted into the profile it creates the desired effect of allowing each one to have it's own set of tags, but I can't figure out to transfer the tags info in to state and then filter the profiles that have the searched tag.

**Profile Component**

````
const createProfile = (profile) => {
        const gradesToNum = profile.grades.map((num) => parseInt(num, 10));
        const getAverage = gradesToNum.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / gradesToNum.length;
        const getAllGrades = profile.grades.map(renderGrades);

        return (
            <div key={profile.id} className="profileWrapper">
                <div className="profileCard">
                    <div className="studentImg">
                        <img src={profile.pic} alt={profile.firstName} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="studentBio">
                        <h3>
                            {profile.firstName} {profile.lastName}
                        </h3>
                        <ul className="studentInfo">
                            <li>Email: {profile.email}</li>
                            <li>Company: {profile.company}</li>
                            <li>Skill: {profile.skill}</li>
                            <li>Average: {getAverage}%</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div className={shownGrades[profile.id] ? 'show' : 'hide'}>
                            <ul>{getAllGrades}</ul>
                            <Tags />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button className="expand-btn" onClick={() => toggleGrade(profile.id)}>
                    {shownGrades[profile.id] ? (
                        <i className="fas fa-minus"></i>
                    ) : (
                        <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
                    )}
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    };

    const getProfile = () =>
        props.students.filter(props.filterByName).map(createProfile);

    return <section className="wrapper">{getProfile()}</section>;
**Tags Component**
```const Tags = (props) => {
    const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

    const addTag = (e) => {
        if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.target.value.length > 0) {
            setTags([...tags, e.target.value]);
            e.target.value = '';
        }
    };

    const removeTags = (indexToRemove) => {
        setTags(
            tags.filter((x, index) => {
                return index !== indexToRemove;
            })
        );
    };



    return (
        <div className="tags-input">
            <ul>
                {tags.map((tag, index) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={index}>
                            <span>{tag}</span>
                            <i className="fas fa-times" onClick={() => removeTags(index)}></i>
                        </li>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="press enter to add tag"
                onKeyUp={addTag}
                id="tag-input"
            />
        </div>
    );
};```
````

Comment: Did you solve the issue to have a combined search?

Answer (score 0):

If you have more complex state handling it's a good practice to use React's `useReducer` instead of `useState` for your `TagsComponent`. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer 
You can simplify your `TagsComponent` like:

```
const initialState = [];

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'addTag':
      return [...state, action.payload];
    case 'removeTag':
      return state.filter(tag => tag !== action.payload)
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

const Tags = (props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const handleAddTag = event => {
     if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.target.value.length > 0) {
        dispatch({type: 'addTag', payload: e.target.value});
        e.target.value = '';
     }
  }


};

return (
        <div className="tags-input">
            <ul>
                {tags.map((tag, index) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={index}>
                            <span>{tag}</span>
                            <i className="fas fa-times" onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'removeTag', payload: index})}></i>
                        </li>
                    );
                })}
            </ul>
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="press enter to add tag"
                onKeyUp={handleAddTag}
                id="tag-input"
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```